# Read/write MS office document(excel,word) without OLE in perl

Tags: perl

How can I read a MS office document(excel, word) without using WIN32::OLE in perl so we can do it in any place we want (like a server).

Comment: Might be you couldn't open the word file without OLE in using perl.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` to read MS excel files, `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` for writing MS excel files.
For more info please refer to links below.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

For writing MS word documents (RTF, .doc formats only) you can try using RTF::Writer
More details here https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/RTF-Writer/lib/RTF/Writer.pm

```
use RTF::Writer;
my $rtf = RTF::Writer->new_to_file("greetings.rtf");
$rtf->prolog( 'title' => "Greetings, hyoomon" );
$rtf->number_pages;
$rtf->paragraph(
  \'\fs40\b\i',  # 20pt, bold, italic
  "Hi there!"
);
$rtf->close;

my $doc = RTF::Writer->new_to_file("greetings.doc");
$doc->prolog( 'title' => "Greetings, hyoomon" );
$doc->number_pages;
$doc->paragraph(
  \'\fs40\b\i',  # 20pt, bold, italic
  "Hi there!"
);
$doc->close;
```

For reading MS word documents, you can use Text::Extract::Word
https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Extract::Word

```
# object-based interface
use Text::Extract::Word;
my $file = Text::Extract::Word->new("test1.doc");
my $text = $file->get_text();
my $body = $file->get_body();
my $footnotes = $file->get_footnotes();
my $headers = $file->get_headers();
my $annotations = $file->get_annotations();
my $bookmarks = $file->get_bookmarks();

# specify :raw if you don't want the text cleaned
my $raw = $file->get_text(':raw');

# legacy interface
use Text::Extract::Word qw(get_all_text);
my $text = get_all_text("test1.doc");
```

Please note RTF::Writer or Text::Extract::Word won't work for .docx extension.

Thanks

Comment: Only Excel document.

Comment: Thanks man, I just need to read MS word document and write it in a excel document for importing it to database. My source in MS word document is about 1000 file and it's a nightmare job...

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is the text content of the file, the easier is to use:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt:text file_to_convert.docx
```

If you really want to extract styles and layout, you will need an XML parser and a lot of hardwork.